# How to run a Maven Project In Tomcat From Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven-2

I am running a multi level maven project. It has webapps packaged as WAR, which depend on components packaged as JAR files

Most of the code changes that i do belong to those JAR files.

To test the changes, i need to repackage the JAR and the WAR and deploy externally in tomcat.

I tried using sysdeo-tomcat-maven-eclipse plugin, but it did not work as expected.

Please advise if anyone has a solution for this problem

Thanks
Gaurav

Comment: looks like eclipse is really primitive then if you either need to convert it to eclipse web app or to use some plugins

Answer (score 37):

**Using the Maven Eclipse Integration plugin**

I you are experiencing problems I've found it helpful to try the command line tool *mvn* for debugging. As a rule of thumb, if it builds without errors command line, then you can run it in Eclipse (but tomcat has problems also, so you might need to clean work directory and clear caches every once in a while).

Other than that I really recommend using the Maven Eclipse Integration plugin! I use the version from Sonatypes plugin repo http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e. There is a newer integration on the eclipse repo, but it works differently and I have not yet had time to investigate it's uses yet.

If your project is modular, it may help to setup the root project as a simple project (no Java , no Java EE). Then import the sub-projects as simple Java projects (again no Java EE).  You can still activate dependency management and run the build targets through the project.

[image: Import modules]

You only need to select the submodules required by your targeted project(s) by dependencies.

[image: Select dependencies to include as sub projects]

For any project that builds war files activate facets for java ee and configure context root under *further configuration available* (this can only be done once, why the option is missing in the screenshot, so do it right).

[image: Select your decired facets]

Then setup deployment assembly for your facated projects. All sibling projects (active in you workspace) should be added to deployment assembly and you also need to add the *build path entry* for *maven dependencies* to the deployment assembly. Once this is set up you can use the Run on server directive to boot your web apps.

[image: Setup deployment assembly]

I find it useful to always stay in pure java mode when coding maven projects. Any smart views in Eclipse only obscures what happens behind the scene, you get access to the specific editors by activating facated projects anyway!

Comment: I wouldn't mess up my POM-files with any maven-eclipse-plugin directives, it only obscures the problems in Eclipse integration. I've have experience of coworkers breaking their environments completely while using it, and it is a mess to explain for them why it does not work and what they have to do to fix it.

Comment: THANKS 1000x!!! I've had the same problem, and the deployment assembly section wasn't configured correctly.

Comment: Since I wrote this answer the M2e plugin has been integrated in the eclipse standard update sites: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo (Collaboration/M2e) I would strongly recommend running the webapps in Webby:  http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-webby/ Webby ships with integrated jetty container and you can specify external containers. The nice thing with Webby is that it runs out of an auto-build-directory, so you don't need any deployment assembly at all. All active projects are referenced through build path, and no hassle with trickling updates through dependency hierarchies.

Comment: Simply brilliant, this is the kind of answer we are looking for here!

Answer (score 9):

I use the eclipse webtools plugin, and run my Tomcat from it. It has a republish method that publishes the jars as well (if not, you just clean the directory and republish).

In the pom file, you should have the following lines so that the webtools will be supported automatically

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me where you got this information? I followed your guide and it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Using the Maven Eclipse Integration plugin and Web Runner**

Setup a facated project (already described in another answer), use the latest Maven Eclipse Integration plugin. This should be located at the update site of your eclipse version under collaboration. In my case Indigo - `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo` (/Collaboration/Maven Integration for Eclipse).

As an alternative to the built in server which often fails on updating workspace dependencies in the deployment assembly (for tomcat) I would recommend using Sonatype Web Application Launcher *Webby* which is similar to the maven directive jetty:run of the maven jetty plugin. You can find the plugin at sonatypes update site for the plugin M2e Webby - `http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-webby/`. Once this plugin is installed you can *Run configuration* and run the web-app from an auto build located in `{project}/target/m2e-webby`.

[image]

I recommend configuring one of the (default) embedded jetty-containers as provider for the servlet-api. If specific runtimes have to be tested, an external container can easily be configured by browsing to a server home directory and selecting the appropriate provider .

The disadvantages I've encountered are quite minor:

- Web applications must be manually shut down, there is no "restart".
- Each web application has to run on a separate port, they do not share container instance.

Answer (score -1):

You get 'Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file "file:..g/workspace/.metadata/.plugins' error with the current version of m2eclipse plugin with the above configuration.

You need to delete servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar from the deployed projects lib/ folder to fix the above error, and setup custom build configuration so that the 2 files are not copied to the deployment directory.

Comment: This is in no way an answer to the OP question.